# find a target pattern in a text file java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, text-files

I have a text file with only +'s and blank spaces. i have to find a target within this file that looks like a spaceship. but the spaceship does not have to be perfect.

thanks in advance

this is the text file with the targets, a smaller version. there is at least 1 target in this.

```
+ ++ +   + + +    +     +  + +++  +              
         +   ++ + + ++    +   +  ++ ++ +      +    
   +  +            + +     ++ +   +  ++++ ++         
+    +   ++++       + ++ +      ++ +                       
 +               +     +   + ++ +   ++   +     +    
 +      +              +       + ++ + +  +       +   
         +  +    ++ +     +   +++ ++  +++          
 +   +       + +         ++    + ++  ++      +  ++  
+    +    +         + + ++  + + + + ++  + +         
+   ++        +  +             ++ ++ +++        +      
         +  ++ +   ++       +   + +   + ++   ++ +  
 + +    ++ ++   +      +       +            +   +  
    + +  + +         +       ++    +     +
```

this is the target

```
    +     
    +     
   +++    
 +++++++  
 ++   ++  
++  +  ++ 
++ +++ ++ 
++  +  ++ 
 ++   ++  
 +++++++  
   +++
```

I have tried Regex pattern reading but the file is too big so i decided to go against that. I do not know any other way to solve this.

Comment: so you want a spaceship hmmm !

Comment: What do you mean, 'the spaceship does not have to be perfect'?

Comment: I actually like this question if properly asked. This looks like a good puzzle to me!

Comment: like it could be 50% or 70% or what ever percent there.

Comment: So you want fuzzy pattern matching?

Comment: @user3520491: How do you compute this percentage? Are Tie Fighters allowed?

Comment: I'd try and look for some image matching algorithm/library since if you replace the characters with pixels (black = + and white = space) you'll have exactly that.

Comment: @Thomas I thought about putting this is a double array[][]..

Comment: @Robin id love to solve it anyway possible. if more of the +'s to make the ship are there then id use that to calculate the percentage

Comment: @Eugene can you rephrase my question to make it a better question please?

Comment: @Eugene you could use that represenation, the point is that it's not a text matching problem but belongs to the imaging domain ([object recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_object_recognition) or "how to find a spaceship in an ascii image").

Comment: @Thomas aha now I understood what you meant. :) Thx for the links.

Comment: Is there any rules? Does the rocket ship have to be the same size and rotation? Can the rocket be sideways or upside down?

Comment: no there are no rules, just find the ship whether its upside down or sideways it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can or need to do anything really fancy here.

You can start by encoding your patterns. In this case, you could:

1. Encode every line as a string, and the lines themselves in an array: `String[]`
2. Encode every line as a string, and the lines themselves in an List: `List<String>`
3. Encode every line as a char[], and the lines themselves in an array: `char[][]`

Number 3 has the benefit that you can easily index it as a matrix:

```
char[][] matrix = ...;
char ch = matrix[row][column];
```

So you have:

```
char[][] search = new char[searchRows][searchColumns];
char[][] target = new char[targetRows][targetColumns];
```

You algorithm could be:

1. For every possible position that target could occur in search, calculate how many characters are equal
2. The position with the highest amount of equal characters wins
3. Get a percentage by dividing this amount of equal characters by the total amount of characters in target and you get a percentage
4. If the percentage is over a certain threshold, it's a match

**Step1:**

The maximum row or column is the total number of rows or columns in the search pattern minus the rows or columns in the target pattern.

```
int maxMatch = 0;
int maxMatchRow = -1;
int maxMatchColumn = -1;
for (int row = 0; row <= searchRows - targetRows; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; columns <= searchColumns - targetColumns; column++) {
        int match = calculateMatch(search, target, row, column);
        if (match > maxMatch) {
            maxMatchRow = row;
            maxMatchColumn = column;
        }
    }
}
```

And to calculate matches in method `calculateMatch`, just add one if the characters in `search` and `target` are the same (but add offset `row` and `column` when you check `search`, not when you check `target`)

I think you should be able to finish it from there.

Comment: its not just 1 target i'm looking for in the file. there are about 10 targets. the bit i have included contains only 1 target to give an example of what the problem is.

Comment: then you search for 10 targets and you find the one that has the highest scoring percentage. just more code to write. give each method its own name so you can easily invoke it from another method that assembles the scores for each target.